# Basic template type manipulation doesn't work

Tags: c++, templates

Why wouldn't this compile:

```
template <typename Iter> void foo(Iter begin, Iter end){
    //typedef typename Iter::value_type elementType;
    //using elementType=decltype (*begin);
    typedef *Iter elementType;
    elementType tmp=*begin;
};
```

This is instantiated using container Iterators.
I know I could be using one of the commented out lines instead, but curious as to why this doesn't work, most type manipulations in  is done in a similar way.

Thanks!!

Comment: I think it should be `typedef T* elementType`

Comment: You are curious as to why some random looking stuff doesn't work? It is wrong on many levels.

Comment: T is not declared, how on earth could this work?

Comment: Why *would* it compile? C++ does not contain any syntax that would make that work.#

Comment: My comment still applies. There's no reason this should compile. You're taking a type and trying to treat it like an expression. It is not.

Comment: It could compile because this code from <type_traits> compiles just fine:
  template<typename _Tp>
    struct __add_lvalue_reference_helper<_Tp, true, false>
    { typedef _Tp&   type; };

Comment: Which is a completely different thing.

Comment: Judging by the fact that it compiles, yes. but in what exact way is 'typedef T& type' is different from 'typedef *T type'? And how is *T an expression?

Comment: `typedef T& type` is different because `type &` is legal grammar and defines a new type. `* type` is not. That would only be legal if types were expressions, since `* expression` is legal. C++'s grammar clearly distinguishes between the two.

Comment: Thank you DeadMG. So how would I write a template function for obtaining a type an Iterator was instantiated with (i.e. type of container elements it is pointing to)?

Comment: Use one of the two lines you commented out. They are both perfectly legal and usable.